# Running multiple rails applications using Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm using Passenger as the application server for rails applications in nginx.Is it possible to run multiple rails  applications using a single Passenger instance ?

Thank You

Comment: You can't run multiple applications in a single passenger instance, though I would think you could put multiple virtual rails servers in your Nginx config.  Alternatively, you can run multiple passenger instances on different ports and redirect to them from Nginx. This may not be best practice, but running a standalone passenger instance behind Nginx has worked well for me.

Comment: yes it is possible to have different rails apps running with passenger. The last time I did this I was on snow leopard and used the passenger preference pane for this. http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely run multiple applications on Phusion Passenger. Remember that according to the Phusion Passenger documentation you're supposed to setup a virtual host with a certain domain name, and then pointing that virtual host's document root the application's "public" directory? Well... if you want to deploy more applications, you do *the exact same thing*. You add more virtual hosts, and in the other virtual hosts you point to other applications' "public" directories.